# c++ new-handler

Tags: c++, memory-management, exception

I had just put together my first public project: simple(sane) new-handler for c++.

It allocates some reserved memory on start up, then releases it piece by piece. It may also raise a signal when each piece is released. It allows to monitor approaching of low memory conditions and  gracefully handle them at the system level while there are still some memory available and avoid raising meaningless std::bac_alloc exceptions.

Please, review.

https://github.com/alex4747-pub/simple_new_handler

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_SIMPLE_NEW_HANDLER_H_
#define _INCLUDE_SIMPLE_NEW_HANDLER_H_

#include <csignal>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <exception>
#include <limits>
#include <new>
#include <utility>

namespace simple {

class NewHandler {
 public:
  // Initialize the driver and allocate reserved memory blocks
  //
  // If not enough memory allocate as many blocks as possible
  //
  static void Init(size_t finalBlockSize = 0, size_t reservedBlockCount = 0,
                   size_t reservedBlockSize = 0, int signo = 0) {
    GetWorker().Init(finalBlockSize, reservedBlockCount, reservedBlockSize,
                     signo);
  }

  struct State {
    size_t allocated_block_count;
    size_t available_block_count;
  };

  static State GetState() { return GetWorker().GetState(); }

  // Full state
  struct FullState {
    bool init_done;
    int signo;
    size_t final_block_size;
    bool final_block_allocated;
    size_t reserved_block_size;
    size_t reserved_block_count;
    size_t allocated_block_count;
    size_t available_block_count;
  };

  static FullState GetFullState() { return GetWorker().GetFullState(); }

 private:
  class Worker;

  static void Process() { GetWorker().Process(); }

  static Worker& GetWorker() {
    static Worker worker_;
    return worker_;
  }

  class Worker {
   public:
    Worker()
        : init_done_(),
          signo_(),
          final_block_size_(),
          reserved_block_size_(),
          reserved_block_count_(),
          allocated_block_count_(),
          available_block_count_(),
          final_block_(),
          blk_arr_list_() {}

    // Note on concurrency:
    //
    // It is a responsibility of the user to call init()
    // before entering multithreaded environment
    //
    // The environment guarantees that
    // the handler call itself is thread safe.
    //
    // Volatile is good enough for reporting purposes
    // because we do not care about race condition
    // between actual and reported usage
    //
    void Init(size_t finalBlockSize = 0, size_t reservedBlockCount = 0,
              size_t reservedBlockSize = 0, int signo = 0) {
      if (init_done_) {
        // We expect to be done once and it is done
        // more than once we do not care much
        return;
      }

      final_block_size_ = finalBlockSize;

      size_t finalSize =
          (final_block_size_ + sizeof(Blk) - 1) / sizeof(Blk) * sizeof(Blk);

      if (finalSize) {
        final_block_ = new (std::nothrow) Blk[finalSize / sizeof(Blk)];

        if (final_block_) {
          // Assign a value to map allocated block
          final_block_->m_next = 0;
        }
      }

      reserved_block_count_ = reservedBlockCount;

      unsigned int blockLimit = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max();

      if (reserved_block_count_ < blockLimit)
        blockLimit = static_cast<unsigned int>(reserved_block_count_);

      reserved_block_size_ = reservedBlockSize;

      if (reserved_block_count_ && reserved_block_size_) {
        size_t reservedSize = (reserved_block_size_ + sizeof(Blk) - 1) /
                              sizeof(Blk) * sizeof(Blk);

        for (unsigned int ii = 0; ii < blockLimit; ii++) {
          Blk* blkArr = new (std::nothrow) Blk[reservedSize / sizeof(Blk)];

          if (!blkArr) {
            allocated_block_count_ = ii;
            break;
          }

          blkArr[0].m_next = blk_arr_list_;
          blk_arr_list_ = blkArr;
        }

        if (blk_arr_list_ && !allocated_block_count_) {
          // All reserved blocks were allocated
          allocated_block_count_ = blockLimit;
        }

        available_block_count_ = allocated_block_count_;
      }

      signo_ = signo;

      std::set_new_handler(NewHandler::Process);

      init_done_ = true;
    }

    State GetState() const volatile {
      State s;

      memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));

      if (!init_done_) {
        return s;
      }

      s.allocated_block_count = allocated_block_count_;
      s.available_block_count = available_block_count_;

      return s;
    }

    FullState GetFullState() const volatile {
      FullState s;

      memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));

      if (!init_done_) {
        return s;
      }

      s.init_done = true;
      s.signo = signo_;
      s.final_block_size = final_block_size_;
      if (final_block_) s.final_block_allocated = true;
      s.reserved_block_size = reserved_block_size_;
      s.reserved_block_count = reserved_block_count_;
      s.allocated_block_count = allocated_block_count_;
      s.available_block_count = available_block_count_;

      return s;
    }

    void Process() {
      Blk* curBlkArr = blk_arr_list_;

      if (curBlkArr) {
        // Release the first avalable block to the process
        // and raise signal if configured
        blk_arr_list_ = curBlkArr[0].m_next;

        delete[] curBlkArr;

        if (available_block_count_ > 0) available_block_count_--;

        if (signo_ != 0) std::raise(signo_);

        return;
      }

      // Release final block and terminate
      delete[] final_block_;
      final_block_ = 0;
      std::terminate();
    }

   private:
    struct Blk {
      Blk* m_next;
    };

    bool init_done_;
    int signo_;
    size_t final_block_size_;
    size_t reserved_block_size_;
    size_t reserved_block_count_;
    unsigned int allocated_block_count_;
    volatile unsigned int available_block_count_;
    Blk* final_block_;
    Blk* blk_arr_list_;
  };
};
}  // namespace simple

#endif  // _INCLUDE_SIMPLE_NEW_HANDLER_H_
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My biggest bug bear:

```
#ifndef _INCLUDE_SIMPLE_NEW_HANDLER_H_
#define _INCLUDE_SIMPLE_NEW_HANDLER_H_
```

These macros are reserved for the implementation (i.e. you can't use them). An identifier with an initial underscore followed by a capitol letter is reserved for the implementation in any scope.

See: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/14065)

---

What is the purpose of this?

```
  State s;

  memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
```

If you want to make sure that everything is zeroed in `State` object then create an appropriate constructor!

---

Not sure what this is for!

```
  if (!init_done_) {
    return s;
  }
```

You should design your code so it can't get to this location without it being already initialized correctly. Not sure how you can call a method on an object before it is constructed.

Since you are using a function static variable for all `Worker` objects creation of this object is already thread safe.

---

Not sure why you would do this:

```
  s.allocated_block_count = allocated_block_count_;
  s.available_block_count = available_block_count_;

  return s;
```

Why is this state not already part of the worker object as a `State` object. Then you can simply return the workers `State` object!

---

I would have defined the structures like this:

```
  struct State
  {
    size_t allocated_block_count;
    size_t available_block_count;
  };

  struct FullState {
    bool   init_done;
    int    signo;
    size_t final_block_size;
    bool   final_block_allocated;
    size_t reserved_block_size;
    size_t reserved_block_count;
    State  currentState;
  };

  class Worker
  {
        FullState fullState;
        Blk*      final_block_;
        Blk*      blk_arr_list_;

        State     GetState()     const volatile {return fullState.state;}
        FullState GetFullState() const volatile {return fullState;}
  };
```

This simplifies a lot of the work you have done.

---

The call to `std::set_new_handler(NewHandler::Process);` actually returns the current new_handler. You may want to retain this value and use it.

If you fail to allocate any extra memory then you call (if it is not null) the originally available handler (or put it back in place potentially).

---

Comment: Thanks for review. I will implement most of your notes. I do not see any point in keeping original handler - once the thing is out of memory nothing could be done.

Comment: The original handler (which may not be the C++ original handler but one installed by another library) may have saved space just like your handler has done. By not calling it you have wasted that space.

Comment: If there is other handlers there is simply no point of using this one.

Comment: That's not true in the slightest. Libraries are know to install their own handlers for their use cases. When you have run out of memory to release you should give the other libraries a chance to do there stuff (they may be able to copy stuff to disk and release memory etc). There may be a whole chain of low memory handlers that were installed before you. If you don't call the previously installed handler you are not allowing that chain of handler to do their library specific clean up to try and reduce the problem.

Comment: The only real question to ask is should you call their handler first or only call their handler if your handler has nothing else to give.

Comment: Note: Most handlers are not installed by the developer calling an `Init()` function like you have. Most are installed by the constructor of some static storage duration object that is part of the library (there is no need for a manually installing these libraries).

Comment: Sorry, this is not intended to be used in libraries, this should be called early from main during process initialization, so if there is a chain of handlers this should be the first one in the chain and the last one used. BTW in 30 years of software development I never saw  (and never heard of) anything reasonable done on out of memory conditions.

Comment: That's the point. Other libraries could have installed their handlers before you without you knowing.

Comment: There is no point of having multiple kludges in memory management. So if this handler is going to be used it should override other ones, otherwise there is no point to add yet another kludge. BTW, libraries by definitions should not participate in memory management because libraries have no information on how they are being used.

Comment: If somebody else has already installed a handler. That has probably done some work. You are now basically giving up on their attempt to handle the low memory issue. Do you think your low memory handler is better than standard ones that have had years of development?

Comment: `multiple kludges in memory management`: Just because you create a kludges does not mean other people have. In short: If somebody has installed a low memory handler you should be using it. This is **WHY** installing a new one returns the original to give you that opportunity to chain them together.

Comment: I once worked on a graphical system library (many many moons ago). We tried to keep all the objects in memory for speed but they were big. When we got into low memory situations we would page out the objects to disc in a very controlled way leaving only enough to reconstitute the object when it was actually needed (object oriented code at its finest). We combined a technique of least recently used but also took into account potential operations that were about to happen on objects, bringing objects back into memory using predictions before they we were needed on a separate thread.

Comment: Sure its slower than all memory, but it did not crash and worked just fine (SSD are fast). If you added your memory handler on top of that one (and that one was automatically installed at startup if you linked against the library) you would simply crash when your `kludges` ran out of memory. Not.a real inspiring result?

Comment: I wrote a handler that will do simple/reasonable/generic thing. There is simply no point of putting it before something that is better or more specialized - it may still make sense to put it after that is something better but it is for app developer to decide.

Comment: @zzz777 The point is you don't know if something better has been installed or not. Its not as if you are given the choice to install the better handler it will be installed automatically simply by the fact that you linked against a third party library. Your code should still work (and behave) when other people change different parts of the system not just after you built in the first time. What happens when somebody adds a new feature and links against a library that does add an extra low memory handler that installs itself. Are you not going to use it?

Comment: @zzz777 You seem to be not considering the lifetime of software projects. The most important feature of code is that it should be easy to use correctly. Without using an existing handler you are breaking this very important part of software engineering. That is not the kind of thing I would associate with somebody with 30 years of development experience. We have all had to deal with systems where people did made things hard to use. That is why we have code review to make sure best practices are followed.

Comment: I spent 30 years developing applications (some of them were long lived 10+ years and 20+ and still going, widely used and the latter one was also big) so my view of the world is slightly different from the common one that is library-centric. I will add optional chaining just for completeness sake. I have a question: one of variable is volatile because it could be changed in one context while being read from another one. Does your review suggest what it will work without marking it volatile?

Comment: @zzz777 My compiler for SISAL I wrote for my PhD in 92 is still being used (I get e-mails from current students improving it) if we are comparing numbers. If you are writing code without using libraries then that's exceedingly surprising. Writing everything from scratch is just re-inventing the wheel (I hope you at least use the standard library).

Comment: @zzz777 `volatile` is one of those keywords that is only vaguely defined by the standard as to the requirements basically giving a hint to the compiler about it being updated out of line. I believe that the MS compiler does provide the guarantee that if it is being used in multiple threads it will be correctly update (but I am not sure). I have not read about such guarantees from other compilers. I don't comment on the volatile in the above code because there is not enough context to make a judgement. i.e. I don't know enough on the subject.